# After using webp images, google pagespeed insight is still showing "Serve images in next-gen formats"

Tags: google-pagespeed, webp

Using Webp images on my page but Google pagespeed insight still showing this opportunities "Serve images in next-gen formats".

This problem is only occurring with the images included in css background property.

I have converted all the jpg/png images to webp and inserted to my page whith the help of this blog https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/make-your-website-load-lightning-fast-with-webp-images-cf55c98ac0a2/ and browser is also showing the webp format images everything is working fine but Google pagespeed test is still showing the opportunity.

```js
<script>
        
        Modernizr.on('webp', function (result) {
            if (result) { 
            // supported
            } else {
            // not-supported
            }
        });
        document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
    </script>
```

```css
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height:400px;
}
.no-webp .banner, .no-js .banner {
    background: #7d7e82 url(images/banner.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.webp .banner {
    background: #7d7e82 url(images/banner.webp) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <div class="container">
        
    </div>
   
</div>
```

Serve images in next-gen formats
1.16 s

Image formats like JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, and WebP often provide better compression than PNG or JPEG, which means faster downloads and less data consumption.

Comment: Hi care to share your site URL as my guess is it is a timings issue (applying the check too late) or you have a minor mistake in your implementation that isn't reflected in the code above. Code you posted looks fine in its self.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Modernizr does its job and CSS background image load in webp format when available, but Google PageSpeed still focusses on the jpegs loaded when a browser does not support WebP format. Not sure if it is a timing issue or a general GPS bug.